# Overlay image on a div in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

***Problem***
how can I overlay a div inside a td?

***Codepen***
[penHere](https://codepen.io/legeo/pen/MqYarz)

***Explanation***

I generate a random map inside a table, this is the function that print it :

```
function mapGenerate(map){

        //loop the 2d array map and change the number with the appropriate img    
        for(var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            var innerArrayLength = map[i].length;
            for(var j = 0; j<innerArrayLength; j++){
                if(map[i][j] === 0){
                    map[i][j]="<div class=\"tile\"><img class=\"walkable\" src=\"https://image.ibb.co/bGanFz/floor_Resized.png\"></div>";
                }else{
                    map[i][j]="<img class=\"nonWalkable\" src=\"https://image.ibb.co/m9s1az/volcanoresize.png\">";
                }    
                ;
            }
            $("#tableGame").append("<tr><td>"+ map[i].join('</td><td>') + "</td></tr>")    
        }
}
```

the map is a 2d random generated array, something like this:

```
map = [[1,1,1,1,0],
       [1,0,0,0,0],
       [1,0,1,1,1],
       [1,0,0,0,1],
       [1,1,1,0,1]]
```

and these are the Css regarding the style of the table and the image of the characters:

```
table {
  background-color: black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px white;
}
tr {
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin:0px;
}    
td {
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin:0px;
}    
#tableGame .td {
  position: relative;
}    
.char {
  z-index: 1000;
}    
#tableGame .char {
  position: absolute;
}
```

***Task***: the character image have to spawn over the div with the walkable tile, not below this.

***attempts***: 
I tried to set relative on td, but the char image just disappear, and I don't know why.

Where is the error ? Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the Char to the .tile DIV not to the td should do the trick:

```
function place(coord, char){
  var charImage = $("<img>").attr("src", char.image).addClass('char');
  var row = $($("#tableGame tr")[coord.row]);
  var cell = $($("td", row)[coord.cell]);
  var tile = $($(".tile", row)[0]);
  tile.prepend(charImage);
};
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RYKZYq

Note that the Char has do be the first child of the .tile DIV. So you have to use .prepend() instead of .apend()

Comment: Thank you for the help, i cannot believe it was so " easy ", i was going mad for the css. So just to understand: the better way to overlap something inside a td is by using a div( with right css position) inside of this, if you put two elements inside a td, the html flow will show 2 elements next(or below) to each other.